# I have found a simple link mistake in wiki documents. Where should I report

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the page http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=indigo&name=gazebo_ros

the website link leading to help ros and gazebo integration is now directs to a unrelated place.

The correct place should be http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros

Where should I report these kinds of corrections ? I have seen the ticket system but I don't know which group this small mistake falls in?  Is there a documentation contact point for the project there was also some kind of additions that could be made to some of tutorials.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191569/i-have-found-a-simple-link-mistake-in-wiki-documents.-where-should-i-report/) by [Ali.Akdurak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20110/ali.akdurak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, I would say that you should edit the wiki to fix any mistakes you find.

In this particular case, it looks like that page is auto-generated from the package documentation, so you should probably file a ticket against the package.

It looks like their bug tracker is here: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0